# Hibernate - Why does Hibernate hit the DB but retrieve a proxy anyway

Tags: hibernate

I have a question regarding hibernate proxies.

I've only one Entity called 'Product' with id/name and category. Sometimes when I call the method retrieveProductsByCategory(String category), I can see in the logs that Hibernate issued a SQL request however, when I debug I've two Product objects, one is plain object and the other is a Proxy.

How is that possible? Why does Hibernate provide a Proxy?

Thank you guys

Comment: One scenario where a proxy would be provided is if your Product entity contains other related entities connected with `OneToOne`, `OneToMany`, `ManyToOne` or `ManyToMany` annotations where at least one of those has lazy fetch type. In that case a proxy is necessary, because those connected entities will only be loaded if you try to access them. I am unsure if there are other cases when a proxy is loaded, but there might be.

Comment: @coladict thanks for your reply, yes I do have other relations in my Product entity. But the question is why does hibernate retrieve 2 products related to a category where one is plain object and the other is a Proxy. As I said, in the logs I can see the SQL statement being executed.

Comment: If it's executing the query twice, then I would chalk it up to an inefficiency. As for keeping two objects, it always keeps one of the original state for comparison. That's where the "managed" part of entities comes in. When you change properties of a managed entity it gets compared to the original on the next flush and the database is updated with the changed fields.